# How to get RecId selected from lookup method?

Tags: axapta, lookup, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I want to get the RecId selected from lookup method?

In lookup method in **StringEditLookup_ZipCode**

```
public void lookup()
{
Query query = new Query();
QueryBuildDataSource queryBuildDataSource;
QueryBuildRange queryBuildRange;

SysTableLookup sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(LogisticsAddressZipCode), this);

sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(LogisticsAddressZipCode, ZipCode));
sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(LogisticsAddressZipCode, City));

sysTableLookup.addSelectionField(fieldNum(LogisticsAddressZipCode, RecId));

queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(LogisticsAddressZipCode));

sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);

sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
//super();
}
```

In `modified` method I would want to get ad read and use the *RecId* taken.

I want to populate the **StringEditLookup_ZipCode** with the ZipCode value.

It's possible to take a RecID ?
The *LogisticsAddressZipCode* Table is's not indexed by ZipCode 
for this I need to take the RecID.

There is a way to save in a global variable or somehow recid selected in the *lookup* method or another point?

Thanks all,

enjoy!

Comment: Your query won't search on the 'ZipCode' field so an index shouldn't matter.

Comment: Hi @SirTroll, thank for your time! You've a reason, my problem is to 
keep a reference to the selected record in a lookup mehod, because, I will want to use the other information of the selected record . ( after
selecting the value fom lookup in the first _StringEditLookup_ZipCode_ sequentially I insert other information's record in another _StrindEdit_) . Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this cannot be done with the `SysTableLookup` Framework. Basically you want your lookup to return two values, the `ZipCode` and the `RecId`. But the framework can only return one value.

So instead of the framework you will need to implement your own lookup by creating a new [lookup form](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Lookup_Form). From this form you can then retrieve the selected record in the `lookup` method. Here is some code to give you an idea how the `lookup` method could look like:

```cs
public void lookup()
{
    FormRun lookupFormRun;
    Args args;
    LogisticsAddressZipCode myLookupZipCode;

    args = new Args();
    args.name(formStr(MyNewLookupForm));
    lookupFormRun = classFactory.formRunClass(args);
    lookupFormRun.init();
    this.performFormLookup(lookupFormRun);
    lookupFormRun.wait();
    if (lookupFormRun.closedOk())
    {
        myLookupZipCode= formRun.docCursor();
    }
}
```

From there you can save the `RecId` of `myLookupZipCode` to a class variable and then later use it in the `modified` method.

Also take a look at [Lookup form returning more than one value](http://kashperuk.blogspot.de/2010/01/lookup-form-returning-more-than-one.html) for additional Information.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is exactly what I would've tried.  What happens when you choose a value from the lookup?  If that isn't working, I'd try adding RecId as one of the lookupFields.  It's probably something where it isn't selecting the field so it's always blank.  That's the first thing I would try.

Comment: Hi @CodyThimm, thanks for your response.
I want to select a record on `LogisticsAddressZipCode` get (and populate) the _StringEditLookup_ZipCode_ with yhe vaue _ZipCode_.This is easy, but I want to maintain the reference to the record (by RecId) and get more information get more information from the same record and use(and populate) in another StingEdit.
But with my code after i selected the record on lookup I lost the reference. Thanks for your time!

Comment: In that case, instead of having RecId as your selectionField, you should have ZipCode.  And in your modified method on the control, after the super(), do I LogisiticsAddressZipCode::find(this.valueStr()).RecId to get the RecId, store it wherever you want.

Comment: Hi, but I have the problem, on LogisiticsAddressZipCode there are more records with the same ZipCode, I will not have a univocal search.
I would to select a ZipCode and taken also RecId.
Thanks @codemann8