# How do you take two field's value by same record form lookup?

Tags: forms, axapta, lookup, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I need to take in my String field two field value from my lookup by same record.

My code is looklike this :

```
public void lookup()
{
    Query query = new Query();
    QueryBuildDataSource queryBuildDataSource;
    QueryBuildRange queryBuildRange;

    SysTableLookup sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(CustTable), this);

    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, CustGroup));

    queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(CustTable));

    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);

    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
}
```

I want to populate my field with combo

```
myCustomTable.Field = strfmt(CustTable.AccountNum) + CustTable.CustGroup);
```

It's possible to get two value ? It's right to use this lookup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make invisible the lookup field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077678/how-to-make-invisible-the-lookup-field)

Comment: Also related and potential duplicate: [How to get RecId selected from lookup method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369015/how-to-get-recid-selected-from-lookup-method/33392845)

Comment: Hi @FH-Inway, thanks for your precisation. You've a reason! I'm apologise, how I have to do ? Very thanks, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Jan B.Kjeldsen thanks too rot your work! I made a mistake.

Comment: Consider deleting your question.

Answer (score 0):

The lookup code looks fine and is aligned to the best practices, you may look for inspiration at the method *\Forms\AifDocumentServiceUpdate\Designs\DesignList\serviceClassName\Methods\look*up, or searching (Ctrl + F) SysTableLookup on the AOT forms node.
For populating the combo as you wish, you will need to query again the lookup table because the lookup function only returns one value.